# Proper usage of search engine meta tags

Tags: html, search-engine, meta-tags

I'm in a pinch.

I recently (around a month ago) tried to make my website friendly to search engines like google. But as an result, I managed to create exactly the opposite, it seems that **my site is not appearing anywhere at google search results after ~1,5months**. My header portion looked like the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>Company title</title>
<meta name="description" content="Description of the site">
<meta name="author" content="My own name">
<meta name="keywords" content="keywordX, keywordY, keywordZ">
<meta name="robots" content="Index, NoFollow">
... code continues below ...
```

I tried later to correct my header by changing `lang="en"` to `lang="fi"` (because site uses finnish language only) and removed robots meta tag after trying to read more about them here: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag

I have problem left to be answered if someone has ever seen similar:

1. `<meta name="robots" content="Index, NoFollow">` - did this stop my page to be indexed even though I have "Index" attribute in place? or was it usage of `<html lang="en">` when site is written in Finnish.? I desperately want to get my site headers correctly for now on and hope or request new indexing round from google?

Thnx in advance. - Mane

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Keep the language as `lang='fi'` if you are a Finnish Language site.
- Change `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` to `<meta charset="utf-8">`.
- Drop `<meta name="keywords" content="keywordX, keywordY, keywordZ">`, It doesn't do anything anymore, and is useless.
- `<meta name="robots" content="Index, NoFollow">` should be dropped, it's basically telling search engines not to both with any of the links on your page, and will be having a harmful effect. If you don't want to drop it, you could set it to it's default value which is `<meta name="robots" content="index, follow">`

The rest is fine.

To check what's going on, search in google for`site:yourdomainname.com`, this will show you what is already in Google.

Then sign up for [Google's Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en), and add your site. This tells you in depth what Google think of your site, and which pages are in their index as well as loads of incredibly useful information.

Comment: Thanks, you just boosted up my skills!

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the real problem with the treatment of your page is, it may have nothing to do with the data you have disclosed. However, it is *possible* that the misguided `meta` tag with `Index, NoFollow` had to do with it. Not directly, but indirectly. When you say `Nofollow`, you are telling search engines to ignore links on your page, making it an isolated page, probably with less weight than a normal page.

The situation can, however, be explained simply as a result of lack of interest. If there are no significant links pointing to the page or if the page lacks relevant textual content or has some markup problem, it is quite possible that search engines never find it, or ignore it.

On the technical side, `<html lang="en">` was of course wrong unless the language is English, but no general search engine has been proved to pay any attention to `lang` attributes.

Basically, there is not much you can achieve by “search engine meta tags” in terms of search engine visibility, but not very much to lose either—except via robots exclusion tags.

Comment: Are there any significant proofs that markup problems could really stop search engines to find my site? No offense but I have been programming to web around 8 years and those sites were indexed by google and this was not :/ So I suspect that this wasn't a common markup problem - but if you referred to my robots tag it might be the case. Weird though that it says "index" but magic is not happening.

Comment: I was not really referring to any specific markup problems. Just that the problem may have nothing to do with the (largely foobar’ed) markup that you posted. If you don’t give actual facts, you can’t expect very concrete answers.